# Remove item in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I want to change dynamically content of ViewPager. For add page I use simple increase counter on 1 then call FragmentStatePagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). But if I want removing page:

```
destroyItem(viewPager, position, myAdapter.getItem(position));
```

getting error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MyPanel{40e80930} is not
>   currently in the FragmentManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `destroyItem()` method on `ViewPager`.

There *is* a `destroyItem()` method on `PagerAdapter`, but that is to be called by `ViewPager`, not by you.